# Admob native ads stopped showing ads with error code 3

Tags: admob

My live ads were working fine for around four days. I made around $18, then all the sudden no ads, match rate is at 0%. the code throws an error 3 while requesting ads. I didn't change anything in my app. My admob account seems to be in good standing, no communication from admob about any policy violation. Does anyone know what might have happened?

Comment: .. is this spam?

Comment: Why would it be a spam?

Comment: Okay apologies. . It was just a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **errorCode == 3** means there are not enough ADs from AdMob to fulfill your AD request.

According to the [document](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdFailedToLoad(int)) of **onAdFailedToLoad()** method, there are 4 kinds of error.

**errorCode 0**: ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR - Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.

**errorCode 1**: ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST - The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.

**errorCode 2**: ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR - The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.

**errorCode 3**: ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL - The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

**Case 1** only happens by a careless developer. It should not happen. It is not user trigger-able.

**Case 2** occurs when a user uses an AD-blocker or network connection is down. It is user trigger-able.

**Case 0** and **case 3** are not controllable by users nor developers. I suggest that you still have to deal with these cases in your app.

Edit: according to the [AdMob Help Community](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en), a policy violation also leads to **errorCode 3**.